# PyGTK: dynamic label wrapping

Tags: pygtk

It's a [known bug/issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=318276) that a label in GTK will not dynamically resize when the parent changes. It's one of those really annoying small details, and I want to hack around it if possible.

I followed the approach at [16 software](http://blog.16software.com/dynamic-label-wrapping-in-gtk), but as per the disclaimer you cannot then resize it smaller. So I attempted a trick mentioned in one of the comments (the `set_size_request` call in the signal callback), but this results in some sort of infinite loop (try it and see).

Does anyone have any other ideas?

(You can't block the signal just for the duration of the call, since as the `print` statements seem to indicate, the problem starts after the function is left.)

The code is below. You can see what I mean if you run it and try to resize the window larger and then smaller. (If you want to see the original problem, comment out the line after "Connect to the size-allocate signal", run it, and resize the window bigger.)

The Glade file ("example.glade"):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<glade-interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 2.16 -->
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <widget class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_destroy"/>
    <child>
      <widget class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum[p][1][2] is the name given to commonly used placeholder text (filler text) to demonstrate the graphic elements of a document or visual presentation, such as font, typography, and layout. The lorem ipsum text, which is typically a nonsensical list of semi-Latin words, is a hacked version of a Latin text by Cicero, with words/letters omitted and others inserted, but not proper Latin[1][2] (see below: History and discovery). The closest English translation would be "pain itself" (dolorem = pain, grief, misery, suffering; ipsum = itself).</property>
        <property name="wrap">True</property>
      </widget>
    </child>
  </widget>
</glade-interface>
```

The Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygtk
import gobject
import gtk.glade

def wrapped_label_hack(gtklabel, allocation):
    print "In wrapped_label_hack"
    gtklabel.set_size_request(allocation.width, -1)
    # If you uncomment this, we get INFINITE LOOPING!
    # gtklabel.set_size_request(-1, -1)
    print "Leaving wrapped_label_hack"

class ExampleGTK:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.tree = gtk.glade.XML(filename, "window1", "Example")
        self.id = "window1"
        self.tree.signal_autoconnect(self)

        # Connect to the size-allocate signal
        self.get_widget("label1").connect("size-allocate", wrapped_label_hack)

    def on_destroy(self, widget):
        self.close()

    def get_widget(self, id):
        return self.tree.get_widget(id)

    def close(self):
        window = self.get_widget(self.id)
        if window is not None:
            window.destroy()
        gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = ExampleGTK("example.glade")
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: May be even easier: See my post at the end. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014804/word-wrap-in-pygtk-treeview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VMware's libview has a widget called [WrapLabel](http://view.sourceforge.net/classes.php) which should do what you want, but it's in C++. A Python translation is available in the [Meld repository](http://git.gnome.org/cgit/meld/tree/meld/ui/wraplabel.py) (separated out from [busybox.py](http://www.gnome.org/~gianmt/busybox.py)).

Comment: Wow, I *never* would have found this. Thanks. I manually added it by creating a containing HBox in Glade and adding the code to insert it in __init__. (If you're really diligent you might create a Glade catalogue file for it...). It also took me about half an hour to realise I needed to use "show_all()" on the HBox after adding the label, so I hope this comment saves someone else that trouble...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-line variation on killown's solution:

```
label.connect('size-allocate', lambda label, size: label.set_size_request(size.width - 1, -1))
```

The above will make sure that the label takes on the width allocated to it, so that word-wrapping is happy.

Not sure why there's a "-1" for the width, but it seems harmless!

Comment: add a second line... label.connect_after("realize", lambda label: label.set_size_request(width=-1, height=-1)) ... to make it size properly on initial drawing in certain configurations of containers and/or scrolledWindows

Answer (score 3):

example for resize and wrap the label dynamically:

EDIT:

```
import gtk

class DynamicLabel(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        self.set_title("Dynamic Label")
        self.set_size_request(1, 1)
        self.set_default_size(300,300) 
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

        l = gtk.Label("Dynamic Label" * 10)
        l.set_line_wrap(True)
        l.connect("size-allocate", self.size_request)

        vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 2)
        vbox.pack_start(l, False, False, 0)

        self.add(vbox)
        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

    def size_request(self, l, s ):
        l.set_size_request(s.width -1, -1)

DynamicLabel()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: @killown - Running that code as is, it is impossible to resize it *dynamically* below 300x300, isn't it? That's certainly the case here.

Comment: Removing the `set_size_request` line *sort of* works, but its behaviour is a little strange. I think perhaps they semi-fixed the problem I mention in my question.

Comment: @detly: oh sorry, yes its impossible to resize below 300x300 but there is a issue, try to remove set_size_request and then maximize the window, after that, you will be unable to resize the window width again, so, it's fixed using set_size_request.

Comment: fixed: using set_size_request() and set_default_size(). It will work smaller than 300x300

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.  Not sure where it came from originally.  Create your label and then call label_set_autowrap(label)

```
def label_set_autowrap(widget): 
    "Make labels automatically re-wrap if their containers are resized.  Accepts label or container widgets."
    # For this to work the label in the glade file must be set to wrap on words.
    if isinstance(widget, gtk.Container):
        children = widget.get_children()
        for i in xrange(len(children)):
            label_set_autowrap(children[i])
    elif isinstance(widget, gtk.Label) and widget.get_line_wrap():
        widget.connect_after("size-allocate", _label_size_allocate)


def _label_size_allocate(widget, allocation):
    "Callback which re-allocates the size of a label."
    layout = widget.get_layout()
    lw_old, lh_old = layout.get_size()
    # fixed width labels
    if lw_old / pango.SCALE == allocation.width:
        return
    # set wrap width to the pango.Layout of the labels
    layout.set_width(allocation.width * pango.SCALE)
    lw, lh = layout.get_size()  # lw is unused.
    if lh_old != lh:
        widget.set_size_request(-1, lh / pango.SCALE)
```

Comment: nice stuff, but for some reason when a label is large enough to display the text on a single line it keep up wrapping, so all labels' "y align" value must be set on 0, otherwise the text will disappear moving up inside the label...

Answer (score 1):

In GTK 3, this is done automatically using height-for-width and width-for-height size requests.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to share how I made Kai's solution work with PyGtk and Glade-3 using [wraplabel.py](http://git.gnome.org/cgit/meld/tree/meld/ui/wraplabel.py).

I didn't want to have to modify Glade catalogs to get WrapLabel in Glade and I'm not sure if that would work anyway with a PyGtk component.  I was however pleasantly surprised to find that simply by putting the **WrapLabel** class in the python environment before calling into **gtk.Bilder()** it will load the class as a component.

So now the only problem was to get the **WrapLabels** into the glade file.  First I changed the names of all the labels I wanted to wrap to **wlabel###**, where **###** is some number.  Then I used a sed expression to replace the classes, but since I didn't want to add extra processing to the build system I ended up adding the following in python:

```
import re
import gtk
from wraplabel import WrapLabel

. . .

# Filter glade
glade = open(filename, 'r').read()
glade = re.subn('class="GtkLabel" id="wlabel',
                'class="WrapLabel" id="wlabel', glade)[0]

# Build GUI
builder = gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_string(glade)
```

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do the substitution but this worked well.  However, I found I had one more problem.  When I opened one of the dialogs with the wrapped labels some of the text was not visible.  Then when I resized the window with the mouse, even a little bit, everything would snap in to place.  Some how the labels were not getting the right sizes when initialized.  I fixed this with another work around.  When opening one of the dialogs I run this code:

```
def open_dialog(self, dialog):
    # Hack to make WrapLabel work
    dims = dialog.get_size()
    dialog.resize(dims[0] + 1, dims[1] + 1)
    dialog.present()
    dialog.resize(*dims)
```

This just sets the size one point too big, presents the window and then resets to the correct size.  This way the **WrapLabels** get the signal to resize after the dialog layout is complete.

There is still one small glitch.  When you open the dialog sometimes you can see the text snapping in to place.  Otherwise, it seems to work.

NOTE 1) All the variations of calling **label.set_size_request(size.width - 1, -1)** on **size-allocate** caused the GUI to lockup for me.  Probably depends on the parent widgets.

NOTE 2) Another solution is to use TextView's and disable editing, the cursor and sensitivity.  However, TextViews have a different color than the background which is difficult to fix in the face of Gtk themes.  The other problem with this solution is that TextViews capture mouse scroll events.  This makes mouse scrolling a box with these TextViews inside it very erratic.  I tried many things to solve the mouse scroll problem but never did figure it out.  Otherwise using TextViews does work.  So you might consider this if your text labels are not inside a scroll pane and the WrapLabel solution doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code that was in the other answers to get a callback that behaved a little better:

```
def on_label_size_allocate(self, label, allocation, *args):
  """ Callback that re-allocates the size of a label to improve word wrap. """
  layout = label.get_layout()
  layout.set_width((allocation.width-20) * pango.SCALE)
  _, lh = layout.get_pixel_size()
  label.set_size_request(-1, lh+6)
```

The -20 and +6 numbers were obtained by trial and error.  It would be nice to get them from somewhere in the widgets, but I couldn't find any relationship to the widgets.  This makes the label resize fine both in growing and shrinking and lines are not cut.