# Word Wrap in PyGTK TreeView

Tags: python, pygtk, word-wrap

How can I word wrap text inside a PyGTK TreeView?

Comment: I'm kind of new to PyGTK, so if there anything details I left out, leave a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text in a gtk.TreeView is rendered using a gtk.CellRendererText, and wrapping text comes down to setting the right properties on your cell renderer. In order to get text to wrap, you need to set the `wrap-width` property (in pixels) on the cell renderer. You probably also want to set the `wrap-mode` property to something sensible. For example:

```
renderer.props.wrap_width = 100
renderer.props.wrap_mode = gtk.WRAP_WORD
```

Unfortunately, if you want adjustable-width word wrapping on a column, PyGTK won't do that for you automatically. You should be able to dynamically set `wrap-width` to get the right effect though; there are [known workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893748/pygtk-dynamic-label-wrapping) like this for gtk.Label, and the guides linked in sproaty's answer seem to do a similar thing.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in the C++ version `gtkmm-2.4`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems this isn't a built-in feature of GTK, however you can create your own TreeCellRenderer, as detailed below:

http://danielwould.wordpress.com/2010/01/02/maemo-custom-cell-renderer-for-gtk-treeview-python/

http://www.islascruz.org/html/index.php?blog/show/Wrap-text-in-a-TreeView-column.html

seems pretty complicated though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer directing at my blog post, was from before I figured out how to do it 'properly'
as Kai already answered just setting wrap width and wrap mode works on a TextCellRenderer
in my current custom renderer I use:

```
layout = cairo_context.create_layout()
font = pango.FontDescription("Sans")
font.set_size(pango.SCALE * (self.get_property('font_size')))
font.set_style(pango.STYLE_NORMAL)
font.set_weight(pango.WEIGHT_BOLD)
layout.set_font_description(font)
w=800  # the width I want to wrap at
layout.set_width(pango.SCALE * w)
layout.set_wrap(pango.WRAP_WORD)
layout.set_markup("my text to write out and wrap at the right width")
```

this obviously uses pango cairo, and you have to remember to multiple the width you want by the pango.SCALE else it is too small to see.

Comment: pango.SCALE turned out to be exactly what I needed to "get" my wrapping done right in pangocairo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While searching for a solution to this question I happen to put this together via different sources. When you change the column width, the text is wrapped dynamically:

```
def set_column_width(column, width, renderer, pan = True):
   column_width = column.get_width()
   #print "column %s size %s" % (column.get_title(), column_width)
   renderer.props.wrap_width = column_width
   if pan:
      renderer.props.wrap_mode = pango.WRAP_WORD
   else:
      renderer.props.wrap_mode = gtk.WRAP_WORD


cell_renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
column = gtk.TreeViewColumn()

column.connect_after("notify::width", set_column_width, cell_renderer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wanting something like this for Python3 with Gtk 3.0. The following works, using Murat's answer and the Gtk3 docs as noted below:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014804/
# https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/enum.WrapMode.html
renderer.props.wrap_width = 100
renderer.props.wrap_mode = Gtk.WrapMode(0) # Can be 1 or 2
```