# Using ToggleToolButton to toggle between ListView and IconView

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I am currently working on a file manager, and I have implemented the ListView and IconView individually successfully. Now I wanted to create a toggle button so that user can toggle between those views. I thought of implementing this by changing the main view according to the state of toggle button:

```
if toggletoolbutton.get_active():
            main_view = create_icon_view()
        else:
            main_view = create_list_view()
```

And for this, I created the event for toggle button: `toggletoolbutton.connect("toggled", click_toggle_button)`

```
def click_toggle_button(widget):
    global main_view
    print(toggletoolbutton.get_active())
    print(main_view)
    if(toggletoolbutton.get_active()):
        populate_icon_store()
    else:
        populate_list_store()
    if toggletoolbutton.get_active():
        main_view = create_icon_view()
    else:
        main_view = create_list_view()
```

Here are my two stores:

1. `icon_store = Gtk.ListStore(GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf, str, bool, float,
   float)`
2. `list_store = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, bool, float, float)`

And I am populating them using:

```
def get_icon(name):
        theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
        return theme.load_icon(name, 60, 0)


def populate_icon_store():

    global icon_store
    icon_store.clear()

    file_icon = get_icon(Gtk.STOCK_FILE)
    folder_icon = get_icon(Gtk.STOCK_DIRECTORY)

    for file_name in os.listdir(CURRENT_DIRECTORY):        
        modified_time = 0#os.path.getmtime(CURRENT_DIRECTORY+file_name)
        size = 0#os.path.getsize(CURRENT_DIRECTORY+file_name)
        if not file_name[0] == '.':
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIRECTORY, file_name)):
                icon_store.append([
                folder_icon, 
                file_name, 
                True,
                modified_time,
                size
                ])
            else:
                icon_store.append([
                file_icon, 
                file_name, 
                False,
                modified_time,
                size
                ])


def populate_list_store():

    global list_store
    list_store.clear()

    file_icon = Gtk.STOCK_FILE
    folder_icon = Gtk.STOCK_DIRECTORY

    for file_name in os.listdir(CURRENT_DIRECTORY):        
        modified_time = 0#os.path.getmtime(CURRENT_DIRECTORY+file_name)
        size = 0#os.path.getsize(CURRENT_DIRECTORY+file_name)
        if not file_name[0] == '.':
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIRECTORY, file_name)):
                list_store.append([
                folder_icon, 
                file_name, 
                True,
                modified_time,
                size
                ])
            else:
                list_store.append([
                file_icon, 
                file_name, 
                False,
                modified_time,
                size
                ])
```

The whole codebase is quite big so you can find it here: https://github.com/hell-abhi/File-Manager

The views are working fine individually, but with toggle they aren't working. How can I resolve it?

I read the solution that is proposed here: [Gtk3 replace child widget with another widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343166/gtk3-replace-child-widget-with-another-widget)

But in my case `main_view` is calling two separate functions that retirns either `listview` or `iconview`.

Comment: Is the code that populates your Liststores relevant to the question in any way? You just want to replace one widget with another widget, no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gtk3 replace child widget with another widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343166/gtk3-replace-child-widget-with-another-widget)

Comment: it is used in `click_toggle_button`, so I provided the reference if someone needed it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks for the link, I will check it and update the question if need be, else will delete it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey how can I use this function to assign the view to main_view during the `click_toggle_button`?

Comment: You don't. You use the function to replace the widget in the gui. You use an assignment like `main_view = create_icon_view()` to update the value of your variable. Those are two different things you have to do.

Comment: so what will be old and new in my case? the iconview and treeview doesn't exist by its own. they are created using different functions

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things:

1. Replace the widget in the GUI
2. Update the value of the `main_view` variable

Since you haven't show the part of the code where the `main_view` is added to the widget hierarchy, I made use of the `replace_widget` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343166/gtk3-replace-child-widget-with-another-widget):

```
def click_toggle_button(widget):
    global main_view
    if(toggletoolbutton.get_active()):
        populate_icon_store()
    else:
        populate_list_store()

    if toggletoolbutton.get_active():
        new_main_view = create_icon_view()
    else:
        new_main_view = create_list_view()
    replace_widget(main_view, new_main_view)
    main_view = new_main_view
```

Comment: it is giving following error: `TypeError: Unable to retrieve a GObject type class from "type"`

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri Unfortunately I don't have the patience to download and read and update your 6 python files just so I can reproduce this error, so I'll wait for you to update the question with a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah fair, no problem. I will solve it myself. Cheers